# Storing values to the database only if they have been changed

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am creating a database application using Visual C# Express and MySQL. The issue is that I only want to store data to the database from the C# forms if the data has actually been changed, the way I do it now is that when the 'Save' button is clicked all the all the fields in the form are saved into the database, whether or not they have been changed.

The solution I have come up with is just to check for every field in the form if it has been changed and then change the SQL command accordingly, i.e.

```
//when the details are loaded into the form
String strOriginalName = txtFirstname.Text;

//when the save button is checked
if(strOriginalName != txtFirstname.Text)
{
String strUpdate = "UPDATE table SET firstName = txtFirstname.Text";
MySqlCommand cmdUpdate = new MySqlCommand(strUpdate, connection);
cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Does anyone else have a better or alternative solution? Thank you for your help, if I was vague in any part, please let me know and I can try explain further.

Comment: How are you querying down the data to be presented into the form? Are you running a MySQLCommand() and getting the results into a table and binding to the columns of the table?  Custom List<able> with properties for each field?

Comment: I know this is quite old, but I use the `.Tag` field to store the original value and then do my compares with that. When dealing with multiple fields, I build the update query using only the fields where values have changed.  `.Tag` can also store custom objects so you could put the field name, type, and original value there so it's easier to build the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use some OR Mapper (NHibernate) for example. It will do it all for you. In addition this will give you caching and other cool things for free :)

Lessons learned for future are priceless and your next applications will be grow faster and faster. :)

Comment: Couldn't agree more. I wouldn't dream of starting a web application without an OR Mapper - but they are even more powerful in the desktop application world where you could keep the data context open for the lifetime of the form if you wanted to. You can pretty much forget that there is a database behind there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have a single update query - unless you have hundreds of parameters, you shouldn't see much of a performance issue.

In the class that you want to update, have a boolean `dirty` flag that will be set to `true` whenever a value changes.

Only update to the database when the flag is indeed `true`.

---

Alternatively, use an ORM that implements [Unit Of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html), which should handle this for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you have single field in the form then this is correct...

but when you have multiple values(fields) in your form then you should use 1 flag variable.

Once any text is changed you should set that flag to true and update it..

Comment: This can cause issues in multi-user systems where two (or more) people are making changes to the same record causing the Last update to the entire record to be the full record. A real world example would be one user changing the Last name field, while another user changes the First name field. If both save, then only the most recent change would apply, where if you only update the fields that have changed, then both changes would be made. Unfortunately, there really isn't a better way than to check each field individually -- a single flag for all is just lazy code :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the way ORMs implement this feature,

Search for `NotifyPropertyChanged` and `Object Change Tracking`.